# Sperner property of a distributive lattice associated to a divisor poset and the free distributive lattice

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets

Let $P_n$ denote the poset with elements $P_n=\{1,...,n\}$ ordered by divisibility and let $L_n$ denote the distributive lattice of order ideals of $P_n$, whose elements should correspond to primitive subsequences of $\{1,...,n\}$, see https://oeis.org/A051026.

> Question 1: Is $L_n$ Sperner? What is the width of $L_n$?

The width sequence start for $n \geq 2$ with 1,2,2,4,4,8,10,15,21,40,45,87 and the poset is indeed Sperner for $n \leq 15$.

> Question 2: Let $F_n$ be the free distribitive lattice given as the set of order ideals of the Boolean lattice $B_n$. For which $n$ is $F_n$ Sperner? It is Sperner for $n \leq 4$. What is the sequence $a_n$ of width of $F_n$? The sequence start with 1,2,4,24 for $n \geq  1$.

More generally one can ask this question also for the distributive lattice of order ideals of the divisor lattice of $n$ (all divisors of $n$ ordered by divisibility), see the comments.

I would be very interested to see what $a_5$ and maybe $a_6$ are and see if this sequence appears in the oeis.

Comment: If we instead took $P$ to be the divisors of $n$ ordered by divisibility, this would give us a product of chains corresponding to the prime factorization of $n$. Now, when dealing with $J(P)$ (the distributive lattice of order ideals), usually it behaves nicely for $P$ a product of two chains, and maybe some other small cases like $P = 2 \times a \times b$. But by the time we get to $P = 3 \times 3 \times 3$ the good behavior usually breaks. So you may want to check an example that contains $3 \times 3 \times 3$. I guess $n=4^3=64$ would be the smallest example like that.

Comment: @SamHopkins Is it known precisely when your examples are Sperner? Sadly the Sperner property seems hard to check with a computer when the poset has a high number of elements.

Comment: @SamHopkins For example is it known when the free distributive lattice (J(P) for P Boolean) is Sperner?

Comment: I don't know the exact classification. But even in the case when $P=m\times n$ is the product of two chains, that the distributive lattice $J(P)$ (in this case often denoted $L(m,n)$) is Sperner is a famous result of Stanley from his paper "Weyl Groups, the Hard Lefschetz Theorem, and the Sperner Property" (https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/42.pdf), though I think nowadays there are also proofs of this that avoid the Hard Lefschetz theorem.

Comment: My guess would be that already $J(2\times 2 \times 2 \times 2)$ is *not* Sperner, though I have never thought deeply about this.

Comment: @SamHopkins J(2x2x2x2) is Sperner but J(2x2x2x2x2) is too big for the computer...

Comment: Interesting. Okay, so maybe there is hope then, I really don't know.

Comment: @SamHopkins I added the question about the free distributive lattice as question 2.

Comment: FWIW, I just tested in Sage and $J(3 \times 3 \times 3)$ is also Sperner, so maybe my guesses are all wrong.

Comment: I can't think of any poset which is known to be Sperner but for which we don't know a "good" description of its elements. To my knowledge, no good description is known for the order ideals of $P_n$ or for a product of more than two chains (of length at least one).

Comment: I know nothing about the subject, but just in case you overlooked it, I have found the sequence [OEIS A341633](https://oeis.org/A341633). If it is not related to the question, I will cancel the comment.

Comment: Dr. Larry Harper's student worked on this. 

Is the Free Distributive Lattice (FD(n)) Sperner?
(talk by L. Harper)
Tuesday, March 23, 2021

Abstract:
For many years one of the most challenging problems of order theory
has been to prove that FD(n) is Sperner – that the largest (middle)
rank is the largest antichain. That conjecture has resisted so many
good ideas that we had to consider the possibility that it is false
for some large n. In this lecture we present a heuristic argument
showing that it is at least asymptotically true. https://escholarship.org/uc/item/8wh6f7rc